# Default text editor for Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS minimal installation

Tags: text-editor, ubuntu-minimal

Anyone know what is the default text editor for Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS with minimal installation?

I tried vim, nano, editor, gedit. none of the above is working.

Comment: `gedit` is the GNOME editor, so unless you added GNOME (`ubuntu-desktop`) to your system, why would it be there?   I'd expect `vi` to be included; ie. the basic editor & not `vim` (VI improved).  If you don't have an editor you like; why not just add one?

Comment: I believe you could find the network configuration file for that specific distro, modify it and pipe that text into a file, then replace the original file, for example echo "here you should copy the configuration file contents and modify it" > /etc/netplan/nameOfConfigFile This way you could set up your network and then install a text editor.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `cat` in a pinch (I needed to fix my netplan.yaml in order to connect to the internet, and thus couldn't install another editor)

`cat - > /path/to/file` then just `ctrl+c` to exit

Comment: Keep in mind this will overwrite the file. If you want to append to a file use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: saved my bacon for the same reason +1

Answer (score 4):

you can also use 'sed' for simple changes. For example if you want to replace the ip address:

```
sed -i s/192.0.2.0/192.0.2.1/ /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

In Ubuntu 22.04 the minimal installation is for machines where no human is logging in. And they really mean it! You are not supposed to ever login. Only automated tools are expected, which of course do not use visual text editors. Indeed, it was quite surprising because in previous Ubuntu versions the minimal installation meant that no regular users are logging in but a few interactive programs were still installed for sysadmins. Not for 22.04.

Comment: Wow... Worked for me! Really tough that no text editor _at all_ is installed.

Comment: that really helps. in my case I was configured wrong adapter

Answer (score 3):

##### If you have internet access:

Try `vi` or `vim.tiny` instead of `vim` or you could install nano using the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nano
```

---

##### If you don't have internet access, of course you have two options.

1. write your config file from scratch using `cat` (it's really not much different than a regular text editor but you can't edit in place, only create new files).
2. and/or use `sed` to edit in place.

and the secret third option is to not use the **minimized** install option if you need more user friendly tools before accessing the internet.

According to the [list of installed packages posted here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474104#post_message_14093486), there is no other text editor. As far as I understand, the minimized setup was originally intended for cloud instances, in which they have internet access by default. So if you want a text editor, they would expect you to install it yourself.

I usually use the mini.iso which is similar. Although it's set up to install over the internet so it obviously assumes you have network access.

Normally, I'll set up a virtual AP from a separate router with a fairly easy password to use during the installation process.

Nothing fancy:

- automatic DHCP
- super easy to remember password

Once everything is installed using `apt` and/or `tasksel`, I'll do the full configuration for networking and disable the virtual AP on the router.

So I guess the 4th option would be to make the network easier to connect to using the installer options so that writing a configuration file isn't necessary to access the internet.

Comment: This requires network, and network seems hard to configure without an editor. Is there an easy way?

Comment: @hey `vi` doesn't require network.

Comment: @mchid `vi` is not available in Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS minimal installation, and to install it you need network

Comment: @Ron Yes, I guess they use `vim.tiny` now. I will update the answer.

Comment: Alternatively, type `vi` and then press TAB twice and it should either autocomplete or it will show you a list of available commands.

Comment: As I mentioned there's no `vi`, `vim`, `nano`, `joe`, `pico` or `vim.tiny` in the minimal installation... there's no single editor available, as surprising as that might sound.

Comment: @Ron You can't/didn't connect to the internet during installation? I assume you're using the mini.iso which is a network installer so it installs Ubuntu over the internet. After installation, you usually just run `sudo tasksel` first thing after you boot up for the first time to install the server and you can choose whatever other suites you'd like to install as well and it should use the same internet connection used during the prior installation process. Just remember to **never use tasksel to uninstall** any packages because it will basically uninstall your entire system.

Comment: No, we are talking about using the current ubuntu 22.04 standard server.iso, and throughout the process of installation you choose "Minimal setup" instead of the default "Standard setup", and you do not add anything additional , and you have no internet connection, no dhcp.. That is how I understand the question of the OP.. That installation does not contain `vim.tiny` nor any of the editors I mentioned above.. Thus the question being asked here.

Comment: @Ron Okay so [this thread shows all the packages](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474104) installed. `sed` is installed if you need to make edits in place. You can use `cat` for creating a new file from scratch like in the other answer shown.

Comment: is the Q about `standard` server or `minimal installation`?? `cat` and `sed` can be used, but they are not `text editor`. You could've tested, as I did, instead of guessing, assuming, twisting or keep commenting NOT relevant points...

Comment: "Minimal installation" typically refers to the mini.iso or Ubuntu minimal and what you're referring to is usually referred to as minimized. Maybe use the right language and don't look a gift horse in the mouth when someone tries to help you even though you're not using the right language for your question ;)

Comment: You're asking an XY question where your problem is that you need to edit a file but you're suggesting a solution instead of asking for a solution to your problem. The answer to fix your problem, use sed and cat as text editors. Sorry you don't like the solution but it is what it is.

Comment: It's usually way faster to edit using sed anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, and I'm a little scared to report that it appears there isn't an editor installed with the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS minimal server install...

Ubuntu (including the minimal server install) ships with a utility to set the default editor (aptly named select-editor; see the [Ubuntu select-editor Manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/select-editor.1.html#:%7E:text=select%2Deditor%20provides%20a%20coherent,stored%20as%20SELECTED_EDITOR%20in%20%7E%2F.)). Honestly, it's kind of ironic, given the following, but... *shrugs*

I ran select-editor on my fresh minimal server install and got:

```bash
user@server:/$ select-editor
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for editor
user@server:/$
```

So I installed nano, and ran it again to see what would happen:

```bash
user@server:/$ select-editor
user@server:/$
```

It seems that, now that there's only one editor installed, it ran without any further input and threw no errors.

To sate my growing curiosity, I installed vim as well and ran select-editor again:

```bash
user@server:/$ select-editor
Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  2. /usr/bin/vim.basic

Choose 1-2 [1]:
```

So all I can conclude from this is that the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS minimal server install *does not* ship with a text editor. *shrugs again; shakes head in disbelief*

Comment: This is unfortunate, I need a text editor to fix my internet so I can install a text editor
Edit: `cat - > /path/to/file` was a usable solution

Answer (score 1):

I have checked :

```
apt list --installed| grep -i vim
```

result after installation of vim-doc

```
vim-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 
2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.3 all [installed,automatic]
vim-doc/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.3 all [installed]
vim-tiny/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

It is:  VIM - Vi IMproved  version 8.2.4919

Comment: According to `dpkg -L vim-tiny` (vim-common doesn't show an executable vim) the command is `vim.tiny`